# How to refer to the variable which is calling the method

Tags: java, variables, methods

**Let's say I have a sample code, something like this**

```
public double {method} ()
{
if (variableThatCalledThisMethod == x)
```

**How would I call for the variable that called that method?** 
(In this instance any variable can call for the method and will always be different)

Comment: What makes you think Java supports this?

Comment: Do you mean `this` - the object that was used to call the method?

Comment: He means the instance that called the method. Something like myInstance.method()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the object the method was called from using `this` reference.

```
class MyClass {
    private double x = 10;
    public double method() {
        if (this.x == 10) {...}
        this.anotherMethod();
        //... 
    }
    public double anotherMethod() {...}
}
```

See more about [**`this` keyword**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)